# Unable to run minimal socket.io server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I just installed NodeJS, Socket.IO and all its dependencies. Then trying to execute code below as per Socket.IO docs

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io-emitter')(http);

var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

io.adapter(redis({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379
}));

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', {
        hello: 'world'
    });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

But it failed with error `if (!opts.socket && !opts.host) throw new Error('Missing redis host');`

Comment: just to be sure: is redis actually [installed and running](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart)?

Answer (score 0):

The line that's throwing is this one, I suspect:

```
var io = require('socket.io-emitter')(http);
```

The `Emitter` constructor expects either a redis client or options for creating a redis client (either `socket` or `host` and `port`).  It is throwing because you're passing an object (`http`) that neither looks like a redis client nor has options for creating a client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please make modifications to my code. I could not make it work. And where I am going crazy is when I look at socket-emitter src, it is requiring socket-redis, when I look at socket-redis src it is requiring socket-emitter. why?